# Adding a new subpage automatically after content reaches predefined limit

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to ask a question: how do I add a new subpage automatically after current page's content reaches pre-defined limit? I mean to create something like Google's search pages, as seen in the image, but I have no clue where to even start. Can someone give me even a hint?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9RQU.png

Comment: It's called pagination.

Comment: @AtanuCSE thank you, I had no idea what it's called and couldn't find it anywhere. Pardon me, I'm still a newbie at webdev.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with vanilla js or some framework? In vanilla, you can write backend for that. In frameworks such as React or Vue, there're routing libraries that alongside lazy loading/data fetching can do wanted result.